# how to call a jquery function from a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have been provided with a jquery script to verify an email and password from a form. I am slighly unsure how to call these functions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    app.login = {
        init: function() {
            $('#login form').submit(function(event) {
               // call functions here
            });
        }
    },
    app.validation = {
        email: function(email) {
            var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
            return re.test(email);
        },
        password: function(id) {
            var elementVal = $.trim(id.val());
            alert(elementVal)
            if(elementVal.length > 0)
                return true;
        }
    };
```

My html looks like this:

```
<form id="login">
    <input type="text" class="input-box" id="email">
    <input type="password" class="input-box" id="id">
    <input class="bottom" type="submit" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have an app login, like this:

```
app.login = {
    init: function() {
        $('#login form').submit(function(event) {

        });

    }
},
```

so you already have the event. Now, you should implement it, like this:

```
app.login = {
    init: function() {
        //fixed selector
        $('form#login').submit(function(event) {
            //If either the email or the password is invalid
            if (!(app.validation.email($("#email").val()) && app.validation.password($("#id").val()))) {
                //then prevent default event handling, that is, submitting
                event.preventDefault();
                //further error handling
            }
        });

    }
},
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks very much

Comment: I am glad to know that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform your checkigng when the user submits the form, you can use `<form onsubmit="foo()">` or listen to the submit - *which is better* - event like:

```
$('#myForm').('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // your work goes here
});
```

---

Or you can do your checking on change of `input` fields, like `<input type="text" onchange="myUsernameFunction">`, again you can listen to the change of this field without altering your `input` html like:

```
// suppose your password field has id="#psswrdFld" attribute   
$('#psswrdFld').on('input keyup keypress blur change', function(){
    // your work here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$('#yourform').submit(function() {
  // your function/code here
});`